# Android SDK - API 10 won't load on device

Tags: android, qt, sdk, android-emulator, nexus-one

I am using QT for programming for android. I was always using- API 10 for my Andorid device and it was always recognized but suddenly it always starts emulator. But I want it to start on my device.. any idea? 
SDK r15, phone is htc, Nexus One, Android version: 2.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. I have reinstalled drivers and API 10. Restarter android and everything seems to be working.